# I am not able to move my site page from Dev server to prod server.How can i do it?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to move my site pages from dev server to prod server.I try to import and export page but this is not work. Can any one know how can I move my site page (wiki page with some webparts added in this page) Dev to Prod server.

Comment: Is there any particular error message that you are getting ?

Comment: Yes like "Server error: The URL is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder or refer to a valid file that is not in the current Web"